# Is there a function in GeoTools to remove unnecessary break points?

Tags: geotools

I have a layer with LineStrings, those lines contains "unnecessary" break points which I would like to remove (it's a projected map).
Is there a function for this in GeoTools, perhaps with an angle or something as a tolerance?

Figure 1. I would like to remove the vertices marked with a black dot.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the JTS [`DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.simplify(Geometry, double)`](https://locationtech.github.io/jts/javadoc/org/locationtech/jts/simplify/DouglasPeuckerSimplifier.html) which takes a tolerance parameter in the same unit as your geometry.